# Почему скрипт не работает?

Tags: jquery, css

Я сделал так, чтобы при достижении ползунка позиции

```
$(window).height - 80
```

(#)bottom_menu панель стала fixed. Т.е она застряла на самом верху(как на facebook)следующих страниц. Но почему то не работает. В чем проблема?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VGVrQ/)

Answer (score 4):

Заглядывайте в консоль иногда

**`if(($this).scrollTop() > $(window).height() - 80) {`**

поменяйте на

```
if($(this).scrollTop() > $(window).height() - 80) {
```

Comment: Да. Уже исправил. Но есть одна проблема, как сделать чтобы при обратном ходе, когда подниму страницу, чтобы седло на свое, первоначальное, место?

Comment: делайте сами код плз. подумайте хоть немного. мало того где-здесь уже была тема подобная.